# Wordpress Error : Tried changing permalink, but showing error

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, lamp

Using ubuntu operating system
i tried changing permalink of a page but page is not opening in tab.
[image]
[image]

Help me out , what should i do.

Comment: please check by debugging, find and change the following in config.php

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

Comment: @PHPGeek wp_debug is false in my wp-config..

Comment: @PHPGeek still after debug log , no change noticed

Comment: @SnazzyGill Have you tried changing the permalink structure in **Settings > Permalinks** already?

Comment: @veesar yes i did

Comment: change WP_DEBUG to true so that you get the error list in the top of your website

Answer (score 0):

You need to change back your permalink settings in the wordpress backend. Wordpress allows you to choose a few different permalink settings, if you have an existing site already configured only one of the permalink settings will work. Just try each one and find the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your `.htaccess` files
and see if the following code is present

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

check file permission errors

[https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/)

Make sure you enforce right permissions to make your resources available to the outside.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

provided your php and apache, apache mods are functioning alright.

finally restart apache/nginx whichever server you are running

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*PS: user you own file locations, where your wordpress is installed, caution before copy paste*

And let us know, if it solves your issue